# Constrain generic method on type argument

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, generic-type-argument

I would like to define a dictionary-like struct type which can be parameterised with a protocol type `P`. The keys are type objects of types implementing `P` and each value is an instance of the corresponding type:

```
struct HeterogenousDictionary<P> {
    var instances: [(P.Type, Any)] = []

    // Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'E'
    subscript<T: P>(_ type: T.Type) -> T {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    var keys: [P.Type] { ... }
}
```

I have an implementation of a variant of such a dictionary where the keys cannot be constrained to any protocol but in my use case I would like to be able to constrain the types for which instances can be stored in the dictionary. The property `values` is an example of where this constraint is important, otherwise I would have to define its type as `[Any]`.

My problem is that I can't find a way to construct a constraint on the type parameter `T` on the subscript. With the version above, the compiler complains that I'm trying to constrain `T` to something that is not guaranteed to be of protocol or class type. How can I satisfy this requirement?

Comment: This requirement just cannot be satisfied. Swift's type system doesn't allow generic parameters to be constrained to protocol types. It would be awesome if it did, I have run into this myself several times, but currently it isn't possible. (And it's probably not coming any time soon.)

Comment: @MarcelTesch So what did you do when you ran into these kind of situations? Any workarounds?

Comment: @Sweeper There are no good workarounds really. This functionality not being in the type system makes you not be able to resolve this kind of relation statically. The idiomatic thing to do would probably just be to have your `P` conform to some `HeterogenousDictionaryProtocol` and figure things out dynamically, maybe based on default implementations of the subprotocols, or something like that.